# JAVA equivalent to Javascript REGEX

Tags: java, regex

I'm totally beginner in java.

In javascript i have this regex:

```
/[^0-9.,\-\ ]/gi
```

How can i do the same in java?

Comment: You can’t say "comma through space" the way you have. Escape the HYPHEN-MINUS character.

Comment: It will also work if you put the un-escaped hyphen as either the last or first character in the character class. No need to escape the space character though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html
Theres quite a lot you can do in Java with Regex

Comment: tchrist You should feel free to be bold in editing, for example, to update urls to their most recent version. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match repeatedly against that regex, you would do:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)[^0-9.,-\ ]"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(targetString);
```

Then use the matcher methods in a loop to get the match you want. The "i" is a case insensitivity flag (which you actually don't need as there are no characters specified), but I'm not sure what the equivalent of the "g" flag is.. I think it's simply to attempt to apply the pattern repeatedly to the target string rather than to try and match the whole string, which is what the above code does.

Also, the pattern above will only match one character at a time, you may in fact want `[^0-9.,-\ ]*`, which will match against 0 or more characters, greedily. I would read the docs on the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class if I were you.

Comment: Using the `find` method in a while loop is the equivalent of the `/g` flag for progressive matching.